# After importing mathview library from GitHub, error resolving methof setTextSize() appeared

Tags: android

[image: e]

I had no problems in this line before. after I imported math view library from GitHub, error resolving methof setTextSize() appeared

I did not have this problem earlier, but as I imported math view from github I had this problem.

Comment: What type of variable formula is? Is that a MathView?

Comment: does it compile? there is a bug where android studio doesn't resolve dependencies correctly on older libraries, however it should compile without any problems.